# Why cant set interval id in react hooks component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's react alpha version, that has hooks in it. I'm trying to code a simple timer, but something doesn't work right. When I press stop, the timer ID is still null, even though it should be updated after start is pressed.

[DEMO ON CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/oj4xq2y896)

```
function Timer() {
  const [timer, setTimer] = useState({
    id: null,
    seconds: 0,
    started: new Date().getTime()
  });

  let timerId = null;

  const incrementSeconds = () => {
    const now = new Date().getTime();
    const updated = parseInt((now - timer.started) / 1000, 10);
    setTimer({ ...timer, seconds: updated });
  };

  const start = () => {
    const myId = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
    timerId = myId;
    console.log(timerId);
    setTimer({
      id: myId,
      seconds: 0,
      started: new Date().getTime()
    });
  };

  const stop = () => {
    // for some reason both timer and timerId are null
    console.log(timer, timerId);
    clearInterval(timer.id);
    setTimer({ ...timer, seconds: 0 });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={start}>Start!</button>
      <button onClick={stop}>Stop</button>
      <h2>Seconds: {timer.seconds}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The question is, why is timerID both in the variable and in the state are **null**? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do call your `setState` function, which should be called `setTimer` in your case, you have to pass a function if you want to update the state based on the previous state:

```
setTimer(prevState => ({ ...prevState, seconds: updated }));
```

Your working fork: https://codesandbox.io/s/244oozmr3p

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's {...prevState} in my case, just thought I would mention if anybody else is going to read this. You helped a lot, I guess I missed it in the docs, I though you didn't pass callbacks with hooks

Comment: although, what is weird, that the variable timerId didn't get the update, would you have any idea why? It's strange

Comment: yep, it depends on how function components work in react. If you put a `console.log('calling');` before the assignment `let timerId = null;`, you will see that this code is called multiple times. That's why on `stop` it is `null` again, the previous value you set up in `start` has been changed by react calling again `let timerId = null`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks, makes sense